# Create a multi-level horizontal flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

[image: Multi-level Horizontal flowchart]

How can I create a flowchart as shown in the figure?

I am aware of the `smartdiagrams` package as described in [LaTeX Cookbook site](https://latex-cookbook.net/contents/chapter9-creating-graphics/9-1-building-smart-diagrams/). But I need multiple horizontal flowcharts simultaneously.

**P.S.:** I need to use this in both slides and articles. Also, the language is not limited to English. I will use International Alphabet for Sanskrit Transliteration [IAST], Devanāgarī, Tamil and Kannada.

Comment: It's usually considered polite and good form if you first make an effort yourself and show us what you've got. People are generally willing to help, but "please do this for me" posts tend to do worse than posts that show that you have made such a genuine effort first.

Comment: After skimming through the 4 tutorials in https://tikz.dev/ , you should be able to: a) place those 31 nodes (with multiline), b) draw all those lines, c) define formatting statements, d) apply all those colors. No big deal with Tikz, i.e. WITHOUT Smartdraw // Look for babel and related packages on https://www.ctan.org/

Comment: @Ingmar : I'm really sorry. It was not intended like that. You can see my previous questions. I've put efforts before asking them. At least, I would've done enough research. In this case, I felt that the code at latex-cookbook.net were readymade templates and self explanatory. Hence I didn't include them here. Sorry again. I'll learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a starting point. Users in the comments have mentioned other resources to help complete it.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mynode/.style={draw, rounded corners, text width=1cm, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center},
  desc/.style={mynode, text width=10cm, minimum width=10cm, bottom color=blue!20, top color=white},
  body/.style={mynode, bottom color=orange!50, top color=white},
  num/.style={mynode, bottom color=cyan!50, top color=white}
  ]
  \node [desc] (lotus feet desc)  {Introduction \& at least Sarga, Visarga \& Poshana};
  \node [body, left=of lotus feet desc] (lotus feet) {Lotus Feet};
  \node [num, left=of lotus feet] (lotus feet num) {1 \& 2};

  \node [desc, below=of lotus feet desc] (thighs desc) {Sarga, Visarga- Creation by Lord, subsequent creation by Brahma, Manus. Pastime of Lord Varaha};
  \node [body, left=of thighs desc] (thighs) {Thighs};
  \node [num, left=of thighs] (thighs num) {3 \& 4};

  \node [desc, below=of thighs desc] (head desc) {Nirodha- Four kinds of universal annihilation, liberation of Parikshit, activities of Markandeya};
  \node [body, left=of head desc] (head) {Head};
  \node [num, left=of head] (head num) {12};

  \node [mynode, at=($(lotus feet num.north)!0.5!(head num.south)$), xshift=-2.5cm] (canto) {SB Canto};

  \draw (canto.east) -- (lotus feet num.west);
  \draw (canto.east) -- (thighs num.west);
  \draw (canto.east) -- (head num.west);

  \draw (lotus feet num) -- (lotus feet);
  \draw (thighs num) -- (thighs);
  \draw (head num) -- (head);

  \draw (lotus feet) -- (lotus feet desc);
  \draw (thighs) -- (thighs desc);
  \draw (head) -- (head desc);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]